# Google map clustering map rendering android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I followed the code through https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

But only thing is that I have implemented in a fragment and I am getting response like below image

[image]

Log:

```
08-25 19:26:59.213 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
08-25 19:26:59.213 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
08-25 19:26:59.213 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
08-25 19:26:59.213 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
08-25 19:26:59.213 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
08-25 19:26:59.213 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
08-25 19:26:59.231 10653-15117/ W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
```

this is only logs

P.S I think I might have found something .

The map gets refreshed and I could see the map only after clicking the map screen multiple time

Every time I click map gets refreshed

this is after one click http://imgur.com/a/R1ROl

Comment: Looks as though it can't load the tiles. This can be due to no internet connection or you have an incorrect API key

Comment: @Tony updated error logs

Comment: @DiscoS2 normal maps are working only when I do clustering this issue pops up

Comment: this error shouldn't be enough to make your map not working, are you sure there is nothing else?

Comment: @Tony no there is no other errors only this and then now when i click a marker i get this http://imgur.com/a/R1ROl

Comment: can u post some code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sureshvaavel/2f41cfa49d8077cff9f7ad22771a2737

Comment: @Tony  added the code above

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own function just use the setoncamerachangelistener and that will help you a lot follow this https://github.com/ReneZelada/clustering-function